# How to download a txt file from Firebase Storage and manipulate the data in it?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to download a text file from **Firebase Storage** and display its values to the user based on the preferences. I just need a code snippet. I tried but failed.

**The error I get:**

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 /data/user/0/com.ritesh.excelfiletest/files/text.txt
```

**Code:**

```
private void download() {
        StorageReference sr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("text.txt");
        Log.d("keys tasksnapshot anf", sr.toString());


        try {
            File localFile = File.createTempFile("text", "txt");

            sr.getFile(localFile)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Log.d("keys: tasksnapshot", taskSnapshot.toString());
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        openFile();
}

private void openFile() {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput("text.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }


        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        textView.setText(sb.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to open file using its full path. In order to get path of file I think you can use `sr.getPath()` function

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution as I wished to but I changed the code a bit. Here it is:

I would also appreciate if anyone told me why "File" above didn't work.

```
private void download(String s) {
        StorageReference sr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("text.txt");


        try {
            File localFile = File.createTempFile("text", "txt");

            Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
            uri.appendEncodedPath(getFilesDir()+"/text.txt");
            Uri u = uri.build();

            Log.d("keysss byte transf", u.toString());


            sr.getFile(u)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        openFile();
}
```